# How do you call a school year divided into 2 parts?

Tags: phrase-request

A school year where the first part ends in Dec, and second in June. How do we call these two periods? Terms?

If the term is the correct word, how shall I call Dec term? Half-term? Term 1?

In the same sense, I need to know how to call Jun term?

Comment: You're going to end up in one of those US/UK distinction arguments… UK = 'term' no matter how long it is. US = semester, trimester, etc. They seem to like to complicate things when it comes to education :)

Answer (score 4):

This probably depends a lot on where you are.

In my case (US west coast), we usually use

> fall semester
>   spring semester

though using *term* might be OK I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

In British English - in my experience, at least - academic years tend to be divided into three *terms*, where a term is the chunk of time that school is in session and students are there,  and two *semesters*, where a semester is half of the academic year, comprising a complete programme of work, after which time the course is complete and students are examined.

This is for university education; at secondary-level education I only ever heard *term*.

As for the names of the different periods, we had *autumn term* (occasionally *winter term*), *spring term* and *summer term* for the terms, and simply *semester 1* and *semester 2*, or *first semester* and *second semester* for the semesters.